# Can I tweet only to a select group of people?

Tags: twitter

I need to send Twitter messages to groups and if I do will the tweets be private and not re-tweet-able?

Comment: I don't know if this adds any value to the answers already given, but I think it boils down to a matter of perspective about what Twitter is. You are seemingly attempting to use it like an email list, but it is more like a radio station... you broadcast, people tune in.

Answer (score 2):

As of now short answer no.  A possible solution would be to create another twitter account.  Protect the updates and have the people you want to communicate follow that account.  As far as retweeting... I believe this is always possible.  Even with protected updates.

Alternative would be to send a bunch of direct messages.

Might need to choose a different medium for communication if this is necessary.  Such as email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's right there in the settings under Tweet Privacy:

> **☐ Protect my tweets**
>
> Only let people whom I approve follow my tweets.
> If this is checked, your future tweets will not be available publicly. Tweets posted previously may still be publicly visible in some places.

Answer (score 0):

While you can protect your tweets so that only those you approve of can receive them, there is nothing you can do to stop those same people re-tweeting you.